# Windows Script (VBS) to always make an application stay open

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, vbscript

So an application vital to my business and employees is our Time Clock. It is an exe part of a larger RMS system designed years ago. When you clock in or out, the application automatically closes. I created a Desktop shortcut to make it quicker to open, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this with a Windows Script.

Basic parameters:

Upon startup of the computer, the script is run and the clock.exe application opens

If at any point, clock.exe closes or stops; clock.exe will be reopened by the script.

I messed around with the script myself and managed to have the script open the application, but I tried to use a loop to make it monitor the process which led to many clock applications opening and finally the computer shut down because of overload.

```
option explicit
DIM strComputer,strProcess

strComputer = "." ' local computer
strProcess = "clock.exe"

' Check if Calculator is running on specified computer (. = local computer)

if isProcessRunning(strComputer,strProcess) then
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\FrontDesk1\Documents\alwaysClock.vbs""")
else
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\RMS\pos\clock.exe""")
end if

' Function to check if a process is running
function isProcessRunning(byval strComputer,byval strProcessName)

Dim objWMIService, strWMIQuery

strWMIQuery = "Select * from Win32_Process where name like '" & strProcessName & "'"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
        & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 


if objWMIService.ExecQuery(strWMIQuery).Count > 0 then
    isProcessRunning = true
else
    isProcessRunning = false
end if

end function

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\FrontDesk1\Documents\alwaysClock.vbs""")
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of polling to ask if it's running, track events raised when processes stop, watch for clock.exe stopping and restart it. This should use fewer resources (*"tell me when we get there" vs. "are we nearly there yet? are we nearly there yet? are we nearly there yet?"*), and respond more quickly (without waiting for the next poll to start).

```
' Monitor process stop trace events.

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
            & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessStopTrace = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
            ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colProcessStopTrace.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo "Test message: process stopped: " & objLatestEvent.ProcessName

    if objLatestEvent.ProcessName = "clock.exe" then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\RMS\pos\clock.exe""")
    end if
Loop
```

( Adapted from http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/misc/events/scr_1218.asp )

Answer (score 1):

```
object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
```

So

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
Do
    oShell.Run "C:\Folder\Program.exe", 1, true
Loop
```

Comment: When the program exits, the script restarts it.

Comment: Ah ok;, i see it now ! clever idea !

Answer (score 0):

You can get inspired by this code from ***Chancity***

**[A Vbscript to checks the launch of a .bat and .exe programs](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/tm.aspx?m=106354&high=check%20process%20chancity)**

```
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then   
    MsgBox "Instance already running",VbExclamation,"Instance already running"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else   
    Do   
        Call Main(Array("c:\toto1.bat","c:\toto2.bat","c:\toto3.bat","%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"))
        Call Pause(15) 'Pause de 15 minutes
    Loop   
End If   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Main(colProcessPaths)   
    Dim ProcessPath   
    For Each ProcessPath In colProcessPaths     
        CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
    Next   
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Sub CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
    Dim ProcessName : ProcessName = StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Commandline LIKE " &  CommandLineLike(ProcessName))   
            If .Count = 0 Then    
                With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
                    .Run DblQuote(ProcessPath) 
                End With    
            Else    
                Exit Sub    
            End if   
        End With   
    End With   
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
        " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Minutes)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    Dim arrStr : arrStr = Split(ProcessPath, "\")   
    StripProcPath = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```